# A small bug in recent reputation changes -- since when 25+1 = 24?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I just visited Stack Overflow. Recent achievments change popup told me that I've got +24 reputation points. However, when I opened it up, it turned out, that I've got 25+1 = 26 points:

[image]

What am I missing? Is this a bug or by-design and I just don't get it?

**EDIT**: *(copy of below comment, for clarification) If I'm not mistaken, score highlighted in the popup (`24` in this case) should only indicate entires in achievements list, that were not yet noticed by me, that is -- those with non-white background (`25` + `1` in this case). Correct me, if I'm wrong, but if I'm right, then there is a bug in calculation algorithm. I have two items, with recent changes, "unread" (not seen by me), which total amount of 26, while score popup informs me only about 24 points. This is the only thing, that I don't get here.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something is removed, it is not reflected in the drop down, but indicator shows it. Maybe on some site a post you suggested an edit on got removed - check "show deleted posts" and you'll see it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, score highlighted in the popup (`24` in this case) should only indicate entires in achievements list, that were not yet noticed by me, that is -- those with non-white background (`25` + `1` in this case). Correct me, if I'm wrong, but if I'm right, then there is a bug in calculation algorithm. I have two items, with recent changes, "unread" (not seen by me), which total amount of 26, while score popup informs me only about 24 points. This is the only thing, that I don't get here.

Comment: @trejder Also it counts deletion of posts. Have you ever downvoted? Then you remember, when downvote is removed, you'll see +1 indicator. But when you click it, you see that nothing changed in the dropdown.